# SQL INSERT into table based on SELECT from same table

Tags: sql, mariadb, aggregate-functions, sql-insert

I am trying to figure out how to do a calculation on the single return from a SELECT and use the results of the calculation as part of an INSERT on the same sheet as used in the SELECT.

In order to clarify what I am trying (and failing) to do I created a simple example.

I have a table called numbers.
It has only one column,'x'.
Each row has an integer in the 'x' column.

I want to find the greatest integer, add 2 to it, and create a new row with that result.

```
SELECT MAX(x)+2 FROM numbers
```

gives me the correct result, 10.

```
INSERT INTO numbers VALUE(10)
```

works, but

```
INSERT INTO numbers VALUE(SELECT MAX(x)+2 FROM numbers)
```

does not. It returns

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(x)+2 FROM numbers)' at line 1"

How should I rewrite the INSERT to use the result of SELECT in a calculation that then becomes the data inserted in the same sheet?

Comment: I would be surprised if `VALUE(10)` worked since the syntax is `VALUES`; just remove the "value" clause - insert can use the result directly.

Comment: Technically `VALUE` and `VALUES` are allowed. If you where struggling with the 'manual that corresponds to MariaDB server version' text, that would be [this link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert) as its an `insert` statement and `expr` doesn't include a full subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `insert/select` syntax like so :

```
insert into numbers (x)
select max(x) + 2 from numbers
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j5xY7Ye8)

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your SQL statement:

- Subselects must be enclosed in parentheses
- You can't specify table `numbers` twice, so you need an alias in subselect.

Correct statement:

```
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (
  (SELECT max(tmp.a) + 2 FROM numbers as tmp)
);
```

For other (simpler) solution see GMB's answer.